# Wrong calculation for decimal amount in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, cs50

I'm trying to calculate the decimal amount in `float` but it won't calculate if the input is "0.01". However, it will calculate if the input is "0.02" but with wrong calculation. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

float MCounting = 0.00;
int MAmountCoin = 0;
float MAmountUsed = 0.00;
int MCoinCount = 0;
float MRemainAmount = 0;
int MCoinOut = 0;
int MTotCoinOut = 0;

int main(void)
{
float Amount;
float MRemainAmount;
do 
 {
    printf("Specify the amount you want in change:  ");
    Amount = GetFloat();
    MRemainAmount = Amount;
  }
  while (Amount < 0 );

    if (MRemainAmount > 0 || MRemainAmount < .05 )
    printf ("\n\n ***** Calculatin for 0.01 *****\n");
        {
         printf ("MRemainAmount Before calculation: %.2f\n",MRemainAmount);
         MCoinOut = MRemainAmount / .01;
         printf ("MCoinOut = %i...MTotCoinOut = %i\n",MCoinOut,MTotCoinOut);
         MRemainAmount = MRemainAmount - (MCoinOut * .01);
         printf ("MRemainAmount = %.2f\n",MRemainAmount);
         MTotCoinOut = MCoinOut + MTotCoinOut;
         printf ("MTotCoinOut = %i\n",MTotCoinOut);
        }
    { printf("Total Coin Out%i\n",MTotCoinOut); } 

}
```

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: On my computer, replacing `MRemainAmount / .01` by `MRemainAmount * 100` solves the problem.

Comment: Floating-point numbers are not a good way to represent currency, because they really are a fixed-point value. It's probably better to think in terms of cents and use integers. (You can still ask the user for a floating-point amount of dollars and convert it to cents immediately.)

Comment: My issue is if I convert the whole amount in cents and if the input is "5.4" then how do I handle the outcome "504" in way that first it change out the .25c coins and then .10c,.05c coins and in last .01c coins.

Comment: An input of "5.4" does not equal 504 cents, it's 100*5.4 = 540 cents. With that out of the way, the problem degenerates into simple multiple modulus remainders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting your epsilon limit.  Since you are using floats you are limited in representation by FLT_EPSILON; if you were using a double, you would see improved resolution of DBL_EPSILON.  (These values are from <float.h>)

```
#define DBL_EPSILON     2.2204460492503131e-016 /* smallest such that 1.0+DBL_EPSILON != 1.0 */
#define FLT_EPSILON     1.192092896e-07F        /* smallest such that 1.0+FLT_EPSILON != 1.0 */
```

Thus if you are using a value like 10000, roughly, you're smallest change in value is something in the vicinity of 10000 * FLT_EPSILON, which would be about .012.  If you want to represent with better precision, use doubles.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the imprecise representation of floating point numbers in the computers memory.

Read up on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Thanks to @m-oehm. it changed from float to integers and working fine.